# Where $−\pi \le \theta \le \pi$, write $\sin (\theta+30^\circ)$ in the form of $a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta$, giving the values of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Where $−\pi \le \theta \le \pi$, write $\sin (\theta+30^\circ)$ in the form of $a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta$, giving the values of $a$ and $b$.

I'm not too sure about how to approach this problem or even where to start. Is more information needed to figure this out or can this be solved with just this information.

Comment: **Hint :**  $\sin{\color{#d05}{(a+b)}} = \sin\color{#2df}{a}\cos\color{magenta}{b}+\sin\color{magenta}{b}\cos\color{#2df}{a}$

Comment: yes this is a question about trigonometry, you would be wise to explore the "Angle sum" formulas in trigonometry to learn how to solve this

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  See [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the sum identity for sin ([wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)),

it is simply
$$\sin(\theta+30^\circ)=\sin(\theta)\cos(30^\circ)+\cos(\theta)\sin(30^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\sin(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\theta),$$

so clearly $a = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}.$

I suggest studying these identities in detail if you will be required to solve these types of problems in the future.